# Matrix inequality related to Minkovski space.

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality

$M=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$
$L\in M_4(\mathbb{R})$  s.t. $L^tML=M$
($L^t$ is the transposition of $L$)

> Please prove
>
> $(\forall a_4^2\geq a_1^2+a_2^2+a_3^2 \quad a_4>0 \quad\alpha=(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4)^t \quad \Rightarrow L\alpha=((L\alpha)_1,(L\alpha)_2,(L\alpha)_3,(L\alpha)_4)\quad(L\alpha)_4>0)$
> $\iff L_{44}>0$

What I can see is that the column vectors of $L=(l_1,l_2,l_3,l_4)$ satisfies $l_i^tMl_j=0(i\not=j)$ and similarly $l_i^tMl_i=1(i=1,2,3)$ $l_4^tMl_4=-1$.
By the Cauchy-Schwartz inequlity I think the first statement is equal to $L_{44}^2\geq L_{41}^2+L_{42}^2+L_{43}^2$.
I can prove some ineuqalities like $L_{44}^2\geq L_{41}^2+1$ by using the first 3 terms of $l_i$ and their linear combinations.

My friend told me it's somehow related to the Minkovski's space and "future-direction vector". I know little about it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can conclude $LML^t=M$ from $L^tML=M$($(L^tM)(LM)=I\Rightarrow(LM)(L^tM)=I$), so it's true.